# XML child position vs document position in XPath

Tags: java, xml, selenium, xpath

I have something like this (with many more elements in `root`):

```
<root>
<a>
    <b></b>
</a>
<a>
    <b></b>
</a>
</root>
```

I would like to find the `b` node at position `i`. What I tried is something like:

```
findElement(By.xpath("root//b[" + i + "]"));
```

But this method to find nodes by position seems not to work with `//` before. How can I find my node?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note the difference between:

- `//b[1]`, which selects all `b` elements that are first among `b` element siblings **because `[1]` binds more tightly than `//`**.
- `(//b)[1]`, which selects the first `b` element among all `b` elements 
  in the document.

So, if you want the `i`<sup>th</sup> `b` element in the document, use

```
findElement(By.xpath("(//b)[" + i + "]"));
```

You can, of course, limit the scope to parts of the document by preceding the `b` step with other steps higher in the hierarchy.